# Can't append divs when using ng-switch-when AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using `ng-switch when` method to append divs. This is the code created

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data" />

<ng-switch on="data">
  <span ng-switch-when="true">
    <div class="firstSwitch"></div>
  </span>

  <span ng-switch-default>
    <div class="secondSwitch"></div>
  </span>
</ng-switch>
```

Its working fine now. But when i want to append something in the div.

Say, i want to append text using javascript inside `secondSwitch` div, but i can't append it because initially the `secondSwitch` div is not appended.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".secondSwitch").html("<p>Second Switch is displayed</p>");

    $(".firstSwitch").html("<p>First Switch is displayed</p>");
},100);
```

Here the text is appended properly inside `firstSwitch` div because initially it is created but the text is not appended inside `secondSwitch` div because it's not created.

So, i can't append inside that div. So, how to overcome this problem guys. Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQA5HFJc0eDoONX8omZL?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed ng-switch modifies DOM and firstSwitch is not created initially. You should use binding to get this working. Here is working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KtrpBaDJSAOW9OHFsqqG?p=preview)

```
  <ng-switch on="data">
<span ng-switch-when="true">
  <div class="firstSwitch"><p>{{firstText}}<p></div>
</span>
<span ng-switch-default>
  <div class="secondSwitch"><p>{{secondText}}<p></div>
</span>
```

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = false;

  $timeout(function(){

        $scope.firstText = "First Switch is displayed";  
        $scope.secondText = "Second Switch is displayed";
  },100);
```

**Update**
And [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/WC5D9tQL9NtBHdGgHSGp?p=preview) demo for binding to html

Comment: For text its working fine. But what if i want to append a div inside that?

Comment: Added link to demo with binding to html

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. But i want to append the div from plain javascript. Can we do that?

Comment: You can do this only when parent element exists in DOM. What is the use-case? What are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="secondSwitch"><div id="replacediv"></div></div>


var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#replacediv'));
    var appendHtml = $compile('<div>test</div>')($scope);
    divElement.append(appendHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-show` directive for this.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.data = false;
  $scope.show = false;
 $scope.change = function(){
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  },300);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data" ng-change="change()" />
 Check 
  <ng-switch on="data">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">
      <div class="firstSwitch">
         <p ng-show="show">First Switch is displayed</p>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
      <div class="secondSwitch">
         <p ng-show="!show">Second Switch is displayed</p>
      </div>
    </span>
  </ng-switch>
</div>
```